# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'SelectedDepartment'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am doing the ASP .NET Web Application Tutorial as a part of a project, and I am running into an error message as the Title of this post

I am trying to show a drop down menu in the Courses page to select a department for the Course selected.
[image]

It was working fine before I started working with **GenericRepository** and **UnitofWork** classes. I have to comment out this code below in my ***Views/Course/Index.cshtml*** in order for the Courses page to even work.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    @*<p>
        Select Department: @Html.DropDownList("SelectedDepartment", "All")
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    </p>*@
}
```

Right now I have an ViewResult Index code as per the tutorial.

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    var courses = unitOfWork.CourseRepository.Get(includeProperties: "Department");
    return View(courses.ToList());
}
```

And I had this ActionResult Index method before doing the Repositories

```
public ActionResult Index(int? SelectedDepartment)
{
    var departments = db.Departments.OrderBy(q => q.Name).ToList();
    ViewBag.SelectedDepartment = new SelectList(departments, "DepartmentID", "Name", SelectedDepartment);
    int departmentID = SelectedDepartment.GetValueOrDefault();

    IQueryable<Course> courses = db.Courses
        .Where(c => !SelectedDepartment.HasValue || c.DepartmentID == departmentID)
        .OrderBy(d => d.CourseID)
        .Include(d => d.Department);
    //var sql = courses.ToString();
    return View(courses.ToList());
}
```

In my CourseController I have a PopulateDepartmentsDropDownList method, which may be needed to change, but I have been playing around with it, but no success so far.

```
private void PopulateDepartmentsDropDownList(object selectedDepartment = null)
{
    var departmentsQuery = unitOfWork.DepartmentRepository.Get(orderBy: q => q.OrderBy(d => d.Name));

     ViewBag.DepartmentID = new SelectList(departmentsQuery, "DepartmentID", "Name", selectedDepartment);
}
```

Any tips in fixing this issue please.

Comment: Can you post your action method for this view? The `Index ActionResult` specifically

Comment: I have a ViewResult for the Index method instead of ActionResult.

Comment: so in the ViewResult is where you declare the `ViewBag.DepartmentID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to edit my Get method (the Index method) in the Controller to include the Filter.

```
 bool hasValue = SelectedDepartment.HasValue;
 var courses = courseService.ListCourses(hasValue,departmentID);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying the name of DropDown List to be `SelectedDepartment`, but in the action you have `ViewBag.DepartmentID` which is holding the `SelectList` object. You are not using the populated `SelectList` in View so what is happening is that `DropDownList` is looking in `ViewBag` for key `SelectedDepartment` for the items for DropDown List which will be populated that is the default behavious of DropDownList helper  method.

You need to use the `ViewBag.DepartmentID` in your DropDownList helper like:

```
@Html.DropDownList("selectedDepartment","All",ViewBag.DepartmentID as SelectList)
```

Comment: It has that red error line under `"All"` saying "cannot convert from 'string' to 'Systems.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>'. `<p>
            Select Department: @Html.DropDownList("SelectedDepartment", "All", ViewBag.DepartmentID as SelectList)
            <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    </p>`

Comment: The C# code the OP provided is not his action.. just a method to populate dropdownlist..

Comment: Also there isn't an overloaded method for `Html.DropDownList` that can contain 2 strings, and then a selectlist.. the selectlist should be placed before "All"

Comment: I am not on my pc, as soon i get back i will update the post